# Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code

Tags: discussion

I am trying to make a post but I get this error:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code

So this post is asking for help on how to make another post to work.

Here is the image of the post that is not posted yet.

[image]

What do I need to alter to get that posted?

Comment: This question should be moved on the meta site.

Comment: Actually it will be a relevant bug report as soon as it is migrated. I would hence refrain from downvoting, even though the OP should have read [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Downvoted-? splitting the hair too thin!! How would one know about meta site. "stack-overflow" came up in the "Tag" input box which would indicate acceptance for this site. Reluctance to read pages and pages of posting guide just to make a post is very common, should be expected specially on a site viewed by many non English backgrounds. Downvoted  payback for finding a bug-sigh

Comment: @FredJ.: Do you ever bother to read the excerpts? [tag:stack-overflow] is clearly not about the site. As an aside, there was a similar one posted a short while ago... doubt I'll find it again though ;-(

Comment: To know about Meta, [it's not required to read any more than the page you were already on](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pcg68.png).