# Seems like a bug in code formatting checker that blocks posting an answer

Tags: bug, formatting

The formatting checker prevents posting a reply.
The reason is "unformatted code", but there isn't any.

> [image]

Up:
The advice from [Mike M.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) below fixed the issue, Thanks!
(blank lines between lines with hyperlinks)

Comment: Your markdown seems to be weirdly vertically spaced. Does removing the vertical whitespace and some line breaks (prominently in the last" paragraph") fix the warning?

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't like the missing punctuation in the (English) sentences. A more standard version of English ought to be used in any case. Try to make it more readable for the average reader 12 weeks or 5 years from now.

Comment: You need blank lines between the links at the bottom. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315366, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313967.